# How to float integer to last decimal in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point, decimal

I'm writing a code that has two parameters, an initial amount and a rate that's converted into a decimal. All I have to do is use a for loop to find the rate if the initial amount grows a certain rate for 10 years.

```
def bankInterest(iniBalance, rate):
   rate = (int(rate)*(.01))
   list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   for x in list:
      iniBalance = format((int(iniBalance) + (int(iniBalance)* rate)),'.4f')
   print (iniBalance)
```

Its the right method. The problem is when I use the parameter `(100,10)` the answer I get is `256.3` and the answer I am trying to get is `259.37` and doing the function by hand, I learned I lost numbers because my for loop rounds to only the first decimal. I've tried using format(x,'.2f') I've tried using `float`, and I cant figure out how to make the four loop work with the full decimal numbers.

Comment: Check out `range`, it's the pythonic way to do ranges.   Is there some reason you're converting to int here?  That could explain the disparity, if you're rounding to the integer.  Cents add up!  Also, probably not relevant but you can use a compound interest equation to compute this without a loop, and that's certainly the mathematically correct way.

Comment: Yes, try removing all `int`s and the `format`. If you want nice rounding do it once after the loop at the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I removed all unneeded stuff:

```
def bankInterest(iniBalance, rate):
    rate = rate * 0.01
    for x in range(1, 11):
        iniBalance += iniBalance * rate
    print('{:.2f}'.format(iniBalance))

bankInterest(100, 10)
```

The output looks good:

```
259.37
```

You don't need to cast the same number into an `int` again and again. Instead of `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` just use `range(1, 11)` (`list` is a build-in name and should not be use for own variables). Keep `iniBalance` as a float and convert into a string only when you print it out, using the `.format()` method.

### Pythonic version

To take advantage of Python features you function should look more like this:

```
 from decimal import Decimal

def bank_interest(balance, rate, years=10):
    """Calulate the new balance with given rate for number of years.

    Parameters
    ----------
    balance : initial balance
    rate : interest rate in percent, e.g. 7.8  for 7.8%
    years : years for which compound interest is to be calculated (default is 10)

    `balance` and `rate` need to of type `int` or `decimal.Decimal`

    Returns
    -------
    balance : new balance including compound interest
    """

    rate = rate * Decimal('0.01')
    for x in range(1, 1 + years):
        balance += balance * rate
    return balance

print('{:.2f}'.format(bank_interest(100, 10)))
print('{:.2f}'.format(bank_interest(100, Decimal('7.8'))))
```

Output:

```
259.37
211.93
```

By convention variable names should use underscores. So your `iniBalance` should become `ini_balance`. You hard-wired `years`. It makes your function more re-usable, using `years` as default parameter with the a value of `10`. 
Give your function a describing docstring. This docstring is available by typing:

```
>>> help(bank_interest)
```

at the Python prompt.

Furthermore, returning the `balance` as a function result allows you to use this function again, for example in a loop. Do the printing as the very last thing after you called the function. Only integers or decimals are allowed. See warning below.

### Warning

Do not use floating point numbers when doing math on money it is not safe because of rounding errors. In Python you should use `Decimal` like so:

```
from decimal import Decimal

balance = Decimal('100.00')
rate = Decimal('0.02')

new_rate = rate * Decimal('0.01')
```

Comment: Please add a warning to this so the OP doesn't use floating point numbers when dealing with money. The OP should be using Python's `Decimal` for this kind of math.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Good point. Thanks for the hint. Modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `round()`, instead of `int()` for your intermediate calculations:

```
def bank_interest(ini_balance, rate, periods):
    rate = int(rate)  / 100.0
    for x in range(periods):
        ini_balance = round(ini_balance * (1 + rate), 2)
    return ini_balance

print bank_interest(100, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Why round at all intermittently? It will only introduce error.

Comment: @101 Most bank calculations are rounded for each interest bearing period.  This allows a balance for each period, (month, year, etc).  I assumed the OP was trying to do something similar with the format.4f in the middle of the loop.